# Calendar integration for Alfresco Share

Tags: maven, calendar, alfresco, alfresco-share, invite

I try to integrate calendar invites in Alfresco. I use this link

https://github.com/jpotts/share-inbound-invites

I download inbound-invites-repo and just use mvn install, i don't change pom.xml
and get BUILD SUCCESS.

Than I copy inbound-invites-repo-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.amp to $ALFRESCO_HOME/amps, then run bin/apply_amps.sh

After that when i run

http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/

I got error

```
 HTTP Status 404 - /share/

 type Status report

 message /share/

 description The requested resource is not available.

 Apache Tomcat/7.0.x
```

Any idea or suggestion how to integrate calendar invites in alfresco share...?

Comment: You need to have an error of some kind in your logs, paste it here.

Comment: SEVERE: Error listenerStart
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: I restart tomcat and now it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you should stop Tomcat before you run apply_amps.sh, then restart it afterward. Here's why...

When you run apply_amps.sh the alfresco.war and share.war files are backuped up. Then, the contents of the AMP files in the amps directory are merged with the alfresco.war file and the contents of the AMP files in the amps_share directory are merged with the share.war file.

Last, the exploded WAR file directories are removed.

Tomcat probably uninstalled your alfresco and/or share webapps at some point during the amp install, which is why you saw the problem.